# Unit test for JSON response, matching against the JSON response to assert for keys and value

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I test for keys in my JSON response.

Currently I am doing this:

```
  assert json_response(conn, 200) == %{
    "success" => true,
    "errors" => []
  }
```

Now say I have another key and value in my JSON response like:

```
"user" : {id: 123, name: "john"}
```

How could I first test to make sure the key "user" is in my response.
And then how could I assert if the name is "john" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split up the assertions like this, although it can also be merged into one assert.

```
assert  %{
    "success" => true,
    "errors" => [],
    "user" => user
} = json_response(conn, 200)

assert %{
    "id" => _id,
    "name" => "john"
} = user
```

Note how the pattern matches are before the `=` sign. An equality check (`==`) is often not necessary.

Also, I can match on the "id" key but the value will be ignored. This can be helpful when the `id` changes for each test.